# Helidon MP REST service tutorial or example with mongodb using DBClient 2

Tags: mongodb, helidon

I'm working on a POC and looking for Helidon MP REST service tutorial or example with mongodb using DBClient 2 (CRUD operations)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found sample code to get started with mongodb from helidon git repo

https://github.com/oracle/helidon/tree/2.0.0/examples/dbclient

looks like basic example.